# Why did the Gaon of Vilna kindle many Shabbat lights?

Tags: shabbat, candle-lighting, vilna-gaon

I am making my giur and got a book from my teacher with all kinds of questions. In the chapter about lighting the candles I found one I am not able to answer:

It is reported about the Gaon of Vilna that he used to kindle many lights in honour of Shabbat. Give two explanations for his extraordinary custom.

I guess that the straight answer that he enjoys seeing the lights and that this seeing strengthened his feelings about the holiness of shabbat will not suffice as a correct answer.
I also do not see (as far as my little knowledge tells me) any halachic obstructions and may be he had a lot of children although I guess that lightning a candle for each child is a rather modern habit?

So are there better reasons?

Comment: We lo ira, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you get great answers to this question, and I hope you'll look around to see if there's other material that interests you, perhaps starting with some of our other great [tag:candle-lighting] questions. May your giyur process be rewarding. If your studies generate other interesting questions, I hope you'll consider posting them here, too.

Answer (score 2):

The [Hebrew Wikipedia article](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91#.D7.9B.D7.9E.D7.94_.D7.A0.D7.A8.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.9E.D7.93.D7.9C.D7.99.D7.A7.D7.99.D7.9D) mentions kabbalistic reasons for lighting many candles. The [Vilna Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Gaon) was a master of kabbalah amongst other things:

> שני לוחות הברית, מסכת שבת, פרק "אור תורה", פיסקה "סוד הדלקת נר שבת".
>   "יש הנוהגים להדליק ל"ו נרות מטעמים קבליים. מנהג ותיקי ירושלים מעדת
>   החסידים להדליק עשרה נרות על גבי מתקן מיוחד המורכב משלוש קומות. הקומה
>   העליונה 3 נרות, הקומה האמצעית שישה נרות והקומה התחתונה נר אחד, וזה
>   כציור השתלשלות עשר הספירות על פי הקבלה. ויש המוסיפים בכל נר פתילות
>   באופן שבסך הכולל יהיו 26 פתילות כמנין שם הוי"ה. מנהג זה מיוחס לאדמו"ר
>   רבי אלעזר מנחם מנדל מלעלוב".
>
> The Sheloh [Yeshaya Halevi
>   Horowitz](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA_(%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8))
>   mentions a custom to light 36 lights for unspecificed  kabbalistic
>   reasons. The old Yerushalmi custom was to light 10 candles on a
>   platform of three levels 3 on the top, 6 in the middle and one on the
>   bottom and this represents the way in which the [ten
>   sefiros](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/361885/jewish/The-Sefirot.htm)
>   affect the world. And others add further wicks so that there are 26
>   wicks in total (equivalent to the numerical equivalent of the
>   tetragrammaton) – this was the custom of one of the [Rebbes of
>   Lelov](http://www.inner.org/spiritual-masters/moshe-lelov-1.php).

More prosaically, one is the minimum number of lights, two is a very widespread custom. More lights increases the happiness and feeling of wellbeing.

Comment: "a custom to light 36 lights for unspecificed kabbalistic reasons" - perhaps in honor of the 36 righteous people that sustain the world?

Answer (score 1):

One classical reason given for lighting *Shabas* lights is that it will enable you to see during the evening. (Citation needed.) As a conjecture, I propose that he lit many lights in order to see better and/or in a wider area of his home.